# aiohttp / Getting response object out of context manager

Tags: python, python-requests, scope, aiohttp

I'm currently doing my first "baby-steps" with `aiohttp` (coming from the `requests` module).

I tried to simplify the requests a bit so I wont have to use a context manager for each request in my main module.

Therefore I tried this:

```py
async def get(session, url, headers, proxies=None):
  async with session.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=proxies) as response:
       response_object = response
  return response_object
```

But it resulted in:

```
<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectionError'> - Connection closed
```

The request is available in the context manager. When I try to access it within the context manager in the mentioned function, all works.
But shouldn't it also be able to be saved in the variable `<response_object>` and then be returned afterwards so I can access it outside of the context manager?
Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Dont you have to await the response before you can return it? `response_object = await response`

Comment: No, the response object itself cant be awaited. Only certain methods of it (e.g. text() or json() ) need to be awaited

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you return it in the first place?

Comment: So I dont need to open the context manager in the main function, it gets very messy if you have a lot of indented blocks. But I will probably have to do it for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care for the data being loaded during the `get` method, perhaps you could try loading it inside it:

```py
async def get(session, url, headers, proxies=None):
      async with session.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=proxies) as response:
          await response.read()
      return response
```

And the using the body that was read like:

```py
resp = get(session, 'http://python.org', {})
print(await resp.text())
```

Under the hood, the `read` method caches the body in a member named `_body` and when trying to call `json`, aiohttp first checks whether the body was already read or not.